# Removing win8 ubuntu dual-boot and using just ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I just bought an asus notebook. It had no OS-s installed so I did the following to it. I installed win8 in uefi mode. I then added ubuntu to the mix. I installed it in uefi mode too using the guide at: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/

I have gone as far as running boot-repair on my installed ubuntu, and have not used the EasyBCD part. I can now dual-boot ubuntu and win8 with no problems using GRUB2.

My question is the following: if I want to remove the dual-boot setup and install just ubuntu, can I use the ubuntu liveCD and choose the erase disk option? I know this will remove all my data, but that is allright. My fear is ending up with an unbootable machine. Can that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could have a data loss.
You should make a backup of the full disk with something like [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php).

After that you should try to enlarge your linux partitions with [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php).

Maybe you could make the backup with Parted Magic too because it contains already clonezilla.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Given that my ubuntu install seems broken, what I want to do is remove both windows and ubuntu, and make a fresh ubuntu install (no more dual-boot). Assuming I don't care about losing any data, can I just insert the ubuntu liveCD and choose the erase disk and install ubuntu option? Will this have some undesired effects on my system?

Comment: @Niteloser yes, you can make a fresh install and you will not have any undesired effects.

Comment: Worked briliantly with the install. Sadly ubuntu seems to have gone belly-up after a first reboot (the reboot after the installer's reboot). I have no idea what's wrong with it. I might try installing the LTS version or maybe mint. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I fear an issue may ocurr when you try to format the Window's 8 and run straight Ubuntu. I had the same problem with my laptop, and I was faced with an error message saying there was no boot device.

I have tried multiple Linux versions to no avail. From what I gather, Window's 8 either locks down the master boot file once installed, or stores it on 'an invisible' sector, that isn't readable/format-able unless the HDD/SSD is completely removed and completed. *I am sure some IT professional will jump on here and edit this comment, as it may be wrong.*

From what I have read, there are some [known issues with the MBR](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160729). If you are looking for a decent guide to fix this problem, then I can point you in [this direction](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1820247). I gather (and this is a good way to confirm), if you place your live USB/CD in after the install and go 'Try', re-installing the OS will come up with the previous install. I know alot of the more knowledgeable folks around here can go into some detail, but a suggestion that is always thrown up is to repair your grub. There are some guides over on my question, or a [link here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70781/after-arch-linux-install-it-just-shows-the-text-no-bootable-device-found) (probably easier)

Sadly I am unable to just add a comment on here, because my reputation is too low. Running the fear of being makred as spam, here is the trouble I have had personally ([my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521419/ubuntu-14-04-lts-install-issues)).