# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Install Issues

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, windows-8, uefi

// Update: I have had no luck in this issue, and have posted a secondary question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526248/hardware-preventing-install).

The first thing I have done (before posting this questions, was read the guide located on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). This was a very detailed guide, and now that I have Ubuntu 14.04, I will try this again.

**Specifications**

- Laptop Model: Toshiba Satellite U50D- Stock. Specs are at this [page](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/computers/satellite/u50/pskpsa-018023/specifications).
- Current Install (attempt): Ubuntu 14.0.1 LTS (amd64) ISO, mounted to USB via Lili
- Error Message: *Reboot and select proper boot device, or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key*

**My File System {Refer to Notes}**

Before I give the details, I will say this- Ubtuntu decided the drive structure automatically, as I do not have a firm understanding of what it should be. I have attempted to re-do the GRUB and Bootloader, and manually mount the drives. This is noted below

- /dev/sda
- free space : mb
- /dev/sda1 efi 536mb (free) 33mb (used)
- /dev/sda2 ext4 741638mb (free) 15800mb(used) Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- /dev/sda3 swap 7978 mb (free)
- free space

**My attempt to boot repair**

I have tried installing Ubuntu on multiple attempts. I have installed via USB and wiped Windows completely. I have then also tried the option of 'Try Ubuntu without installing' and then installing. On both methods, the Ubuntu installer has recognized the previous install, and I have overwritten it. Once all has installed, it prompts for a reboot..where it gets the above error message. Just to clarify- I have **not** been able to boot directly to Ubuntu, and there is currently no OS other than Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop.

The first instance, I installed a Grub repair program and went with that. The guide in which I followed is hosted on the Community. You can view this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). As per the instructions, the first command(s) I ran were as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

This went through the terminal with no issue. Once it completed, it recommended I run the following commands:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed linux-signed*
```

Upon completion, I rebooted and all was the same- no luck!

**Repair Grub2**

So with the above not working, I tried the next [guide](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). Now, this one I was not so sure on. Because I had booted from the USB, I decided to add an admin account for myself- what was the harm? I was not too certain on this one, **so point out any mistakes please!**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

There were no errors, prompts etc. so I assume when you mount there is no confirmation etc. I then ran the following commands:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Once again, nothing happened- which is what I expected. I then ran the next command:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now that I was done, I went with the next command of:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

This is where I ran into the following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub/grub_0.97-29ubuntu66_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'au.archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am not sure if an error of the file no longer exists, or is outdated etc. In this instance **I did what any idiot does. I improvised.**

```
sudo apt-get install grub or apt-get install grub
```

When that spat out errors, I reverted to an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

No help. For those interested, the terminal reads this:

```
   root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install grub
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  efibootmgr secureboot-db shim
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  grub-common
Suggested packages:
  grub-legacy-doc mdadm multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub grub-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,593 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I was then unable to perform the next step, which is:

```
    exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

With that, I decided to revert back to my **System File Stricture.**

**The Next Step...**

I have looked around for a simple guide on how a file-structure should be, and attempted this [guide](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/ubuntu-1204-lts/hard-disk-partition/).

As per the instructions, the first step was to do. This was fun..

```
sudo lshw -c disk
```

The logical name of my drive is/dev/sda. Awesome, now I follow this up.

Unfortunately I could not find the disk utility (Yo, askubuntu- 10 points for n00b). I went into the next available option...the terminal! I start fdisk with the following:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

Then enter 'm' for menu, 'n' for new and followed the details. The new partition was made, so then I formatted with:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dec/sdb1
```

I read, then re-read the guide and no luck..no boot device. Frustrated, I tried **check disk for defects**. Apparently all good. I am greatly exceeded my knowledge of Ubuntu/Linux.

**Updates**

I have now tried to install Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Debian- also using different Live USB creators. All has resulted in the same. I  have/am purchasing a small SSD and 16GB Ram- we will see if a different hard drive helps the situation.

I gathered as much, as I believe it is an issue with UEFI/Safe Boot and is on the motherboard.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu alongside Windows and then removed the Windows partition? If that's the case, then you have to [repair grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (the bootloader).

Comment: @ToDo Hi! No sorry, booted to Live USB and installed from there, wiping Windows. There is no separate partition, just one manifest of Linux!

Comment: Try repairing grub just the same.

Comment: @ToDo Thank you for your assistance. I have updated my post for a little more information and are attempting to repair now.

Comment: Your laptop is trying to boot to ubuntu in uefi mode try to boot in legacy mode or CSM.

Comment: Karthik- I have turned secureboot off, and enabled legacy in the BIOS and vice versa...is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is based on an answer posted on the question "[Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (EUFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported?lq=1)." So, I did as follows:

1- I made a parition on my SSD using the default Window's Disk Management Tool

2- I then grabbed the latest version of [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) and made a bootable EUFI & Safeboot USB with [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

3- I then enabled Secure Boot in my Bios (after performing the CMD command as per the answer on the other question), and continued installing Ubuntu.

**Note: I selected Something Else, and manually made my Root 80GB, Swap 5GB and EFI 5GB** Now pay attention, this is something I did without reading the guide (although it may be in there..)

After installing the Ubuntu system, I was booting straigh to Window's 8. I followed these steps:

4- I then booted into the Advanced Options (**Shift + Restart)** and went Advanced Options > Window's Startup Settings > **Elected my Ubuntu Boot**. Viola! It worked, went straigh to my Ubuntu install with no issues.

For piece of mind, I then used GParted to format my Window's Partition and did a grub repair. Finally, I am now a happy Linux user. Whilst I was unable to boot before to Linux directly, using Dual Boot afforded me the option of electing my boot.

I know this has worked for me, however I cannot confirm if it will work for others.

Answer (score -1):

From the error message it looks like your system is trying to boot from a media device such as CD or USB (probably the one you used for installation).
Thus try to go in the BIOS of you computer and change the boot device priority, selecting the drive where linux is installed. If this does not work (or you did it already) then fall back to other installation issues.

Comment: Alex, if I have the installation USB present, it will boot to that. When there is no USB, I get the error message in the above post. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Comment: Are you sure the computer actually tries to boot from the hard drive and it does not tries only from the USB?

Comment: Alex, the boot priority is HDD/SSD, Network Device then USB. My understanding is, it points to priority 1 and if not present, goes down the list. I'll also see if I have the capability to manually select my boot item. I'd love it if the problem was that straightforward, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: OK the boot device priority should be good then. I wander what kind of partition did you make on the HDD. If I remember well the system boots from the master partition, if the bootable installation is on another partition then it does not work.

Comment: Alex, pleased refer to the post, as it has my file structure..this was automatically done by the installer. Once I've gone into Ubuntu, I note that the installation is also on sda2.