# Can't boot from USB on Win8

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-8

Every time I go to boot Ubuntu to install on a separate partition, it tells me there's no bootable disk/drive. I know the ISO is uncorrupted. However, when I start my laptop, it gives the option to boot to Ubuntu, but it tells me there's an error and makes me restart.

Comment: How did you put the ISO on USB?

Comment: Copying the ISO to the stick will not obtain the results you need. You must effectively "burn" the image to a USB stick similar to creating a boot CD/DVD. Instructions can be found here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Skylar, please advise how you are performing this. I'm on my phone, so I will refine at a later date.

Step 1- Create the partition in Windows.

In your Window's 8  OS, right click on Computer, select manage and go to disk management. From here, create the desired partition for Linux- try to make a minimum of 20GB.

Step 2- Burn the ISO

There are several tools in which you can use, I would recommend using RUFUS to perform this. Now in regards to the iso file, I would recommend using one of the later Linux versions- e.g. Ubuntu 14.04.

If you do use RUFUS, select MBR or UEFI for Secure Boot machines. Once the iso has been burned to the USB, reboot the machine and boot to USB; either edit this in your Bios or manually select it. To manually select it you will need to go to the boot manager; this is usually achieved by pressing F12 on boot.

Step 3- Installation

From here, complete the setup as desired. When it comes to the disk selection, ensure you select something else and then install to your partition. You'll just need to make "/", and a swap area, plus whatever else you need. You should not need an EFI boot section as it will write to the Windows MBR, but if you're really worried you can dedicate 100mb to this.

If you're unsure of any of the steps, please let me know.  Here are some links to help:

Here is a quick link to my blog where I have complete a guide and referenced other guides: http://bit.ly/1s4oceI

Here is the link to the issues I have had with, where you may find some useful comments: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Install Issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/521419/212930)

Lastly, I would highly recommend you reading this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/212930

If I've taken your question in the wrong direction please let me know. If it does not help, please update your question with your method, and the outcome.

Comment: Before I saw this, I did create the partition, I did burn the ISO to my USB and preformed the install. I did look at a video for the install, and everything went swimmingly. However, when I try to choose ubuntu from my dual-boot screen, it says that I'm missing "/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr”. I turned off secure boot, so I'm going to attempt to do a boot repair. If you could advise in anyway possible.

Comment: In the first instance I would suggest the boot repair. You did not use WUBI to do the install? If you are using a later ISO like `Ubuntu 14.04` then you should be able to install in Safe/Secure Boot. Your error messages seems to indicate Safeboot is not allowing Ubuntu to write to the MBR..this could be due to an outdated ISO that, thanks to Microsoft, is not supported in the UEFI scheme. If you are really dedicated, try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Comment: I really want to use ubuntu, because I have a linux class next semester in my school, and I wanted to get a head start. But I do have one question, if I were to "upgrade" to Windows 7, would UEFI/secure boot be an issue or is it in the BIOS?

Comment: Installing Windows 7 would also be a pain. If this is for testing purposes, you'd probably be best to run a virtual box within Windows 8, yes?

Comment: I could, but I don't exactly have the power to run it effectively.

Comment: Still an issue?